# grails strategies for managing custom plugins

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have modified some grails plugins to customize them for my needs. I am deciding how to best manage these customizations. My thought was to put them in a separate project (which is version controlled) and upload them to my Nexus repository. It seems a little unclean to package the plugin source as part of the project (and check them into version control with the project).

I prefer to have my plugins installed to the .grails directory. Is this the preferred approach for dealing with grails pluging customizations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nexus approach is a good one. It's best to rename the plugin, e.g. with a company-specific suffix, so there's no ambiguity which one you're using.